# How can JSON objects with coordinates update over time?

Tags: android, google-maps

How do you get a JSON OBJECT coordinate location to continuously update with the marker across the map?

Comment: Start by getting a map fragment into your activity.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/code-samples You will need to learn how to get the API key and work with Google APIs.  There are lots of code samples and documentation.  When you get stuck, post the code that is giving you heartburn and the community will be better able to help you.